# How to get a select's options by first and last characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select an option to be viewed from a select dropdown. The code works by selecting the first characters of the element (e.g "Wood_20Sept" "Fire_20Sept" "Water_20Sept"). Snippet of the working code:

```
filterList(document.getElementById("worldElementsList"), /^Wood/i);
```

So this would select any options with the word "wood". 
Like:

- "Wood_20Sept"
- "Wood_20Mar"
- "Wood_20May"

Problem is now there is a version 2 of these groups  ("Wood_20Sept_V1" "Wood_20Sept_V2" "Fire_20SeptV1" "Fire_20SeptV2")

So I want to select the options by first and last: "Wood" and "V2".

So basically I need the code to say this:

```
filterList(document.getElementById("bankInfoList"), /^Wood/i && /v2$/i);
```

But that will only select the "V2"

Comment: `/^Wood(.*)v2$/i` - must begin with Wood, end with v2 ... and have arbitrary characters in between.

Comment: do these options in dropdowns not have ID attributes that you can select by? That would be more reliable.

Comment: Thank you, your an absolute life saver :)

Comment: I'll put the whole code up when I have time, basically the options are pulled in via java and then are shown and hidden via radio buttons. It's all abit of a mashed up work around the bug with IE11 where options can't have display:none, so you have to save the list.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

A.Take whole string as a array
B. Find array[length-1] and array[length-2]

To match last elements with your string